# Cannot install .NET core 3.1.100

Tags: .net-core

I had installed a preview version of .net core 3.1.
After .net core 3.1 was released, I followed the uninstallation steps for the preview version and started the installation of .net core 3.1.100, but it fails.

In the log file I find the following lines:

> [3CB4:073C][2019-12-19T00:25:45]i052: Condition 'WixBundleInstalled OR
>   ((NOT (DOTNETHOME_X64 ~= DOTNETHOME_X86)) OR
>   DOTNETHOMESIMILARITYCHECKOVERRIDE)' evaluates to true.
>   [3CB4:073C][2019-12-19T00:25:45]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
>   [3CB4:35F0][2019-12-19T00:25:48]e000: Error 0x80070666: Cannot install
>   a product when a newer version is installed.

I've tried to uninstall all .net core SDKs, manual clean up of dotnet folders and even uninstallation of visual studio.
Still, I'm in the same situation. 
It seems that somewhere in registers is stored any env variable that prevents installation.

Has anybody faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try uninstalling Visual C++ redistributable and then installing dot net core.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I completely uninstalled Visual Studio and Visual C++ redistributable. Now it's fixed.